# What is the strength of human cornea?

Tags: eyes, biophysics

What is the difference of pressure a human eyeball cornea (cornea, lens and other elements separating vitreous body from air) can handle? Or asking differently: what the outside pressure should be to "blow up" a healthy man's eyeball?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normal pressure in the eye<sup>[1](http://www.webmd.com/eye-health/tonometry?page=3),[2](http://www.emedicinehealth.com/glaucoma_overview/article_em.htm)</sup> is between 10 and 21 mmHg (somewhere around 1.3-2.8 kPa or 0.01-0.03 atm) with pathology occurring at around 30 mmHg.<sup>[3](http://www.uniklinikum-saarland.de/de/einrichtungen/kliniken_institute/experimentelle_ophthalmologie/forschung/iop_sensing/)</sup>  Clearly the cornea can handle that, but how much more?  There's a lot more evidence as far as I could see for how well surgeries hold up, with 150-300+ mmHg (20-40 kPa, 0.2-0.4 atm).<sup>[4](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/21761419)</sup>  One source<sup>[5](http://ac.els-cdn.com/S0079670097000361/1-s2.0-S0079670097000361-main.pdf?_tid=b96e9016-35d5-11e3-b5c3-00000aab0f27&acdnat=1381867961_2f422e3bf7a9ef106026e1beaa009ad5)</sup> from 1998 cites work supposedly showing that the [stroma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Corneal_stroma):

> gives the cornea 100 times more strength than is necessary to withstand the maximum intraocular pressure under physiological conditions.

So maybe around 200 kPa, for just the stroma?  Interestingly, a [new eye layer was discovered](http://www.natureworldnews.com/articles/2403/20130612/cornea-layer-discovery-make-eye-surgeries-safer-researchers.htm) earlier this year; this Dua's Layer is incredibly thin - 15 microns - but can withstand pressures of around 100-200 kPa (750-1500 mmHg, 1-2 atm).<sup>[6](http://medtube.net/tribune/new-anatomical-structure-in-the-cornea-of-%E2%80%8B%E2%80%8Bthe-human-eye/),[7](http://www.biosciencetechnology.com/articles/2013/08/commotion-over-new-cornea-layer#.Ul2hPSSoU2U)</sup>  The large range there is due to some conflicting numbers in those links; the 200 kPa is the more widely reported one, but again, that's just for one layer.

Then, of course, there is this: a beautiful 2009 [thesis by Jill Aliza Bisplinghoff from Virginia Tech](http://scholar.lib.vt.edu/theses/available/etd-04242009-094655/unrestricted/Bisplinghoff_Thesis-R3.pdf) which thoroughly examines the issue.  As an answer to your question, it includes the following such gems:

> The high rate pressurization of 20 human eyes resulted in a mean rupture pressure of **0.97 ± 0.29 MPa (7275.60 ± 2175.18 mm Hg)**... A student T-test revealed that the difference in the rupture pressure between the equatorial mean of 0.93 ± 0.30 MPa (6975.57 ± 2250.19 mm Hg) and the meridional mean of 1.13 ± 0.21 MPa (8475.70 ± 1575.13 mm Hg) was not significant (p=0.16)

and

> A pneumatic cannon was used to impact eyes with a variety of projectiles at multiple velocities... The projectiles selected for the test series included a 6.35 mm diameter metal ball, a 9.25 mm diameter aluminum rod, and an 11.16 mm diameter aluminum rod... A range of internal eye pressures were produced that varied from **1256 mmHg (24.3 psi) to 22843 mmHg (442 psi)**... [and] resulted in zero globe rupture.

Comment: Every time you mean the relative pressure, not the absolute right? Anyway, thanks for the answer! :-)

Comment: @Jantomedes Most of these are absolute pressures, internal where appropriate.